# Is it possible to let the user defines the field of matrix in haskell?

Tags: haskell, matrix, field

Hi guys i have been wondering how i can let the user to define the field(row,column) of matrix in haskell.

For example, the user should enter a value for the field and than the user should enter a matrix. If the user enters more value then what he defined in field than the program should show an Exception.

(e.g. `maxIndex=3 matrix [[1,2,3],[4,3,5],[3,7,8],[5,6,8]] -> Exception:Out of range`)

Answer (score 1):

Define an own type that behaves that way?

```
data Matrix = Matrix [[Int]] Int {-rows-} Int {-columns-}

-- constructor / accessor functions that do bounds checking
```

Linked Lists are pretty terrible for representing matrices btw. If you actually need something like that, you should look into existing packages like [hmatrix](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hmatrix).

Comment: Cant we take the value of row and column from the user with other function first and than take the matrix?
(e.g. rowColumn <- 3 Matrix <-[[1,2,3],....] )